# Execution failed for task ':app:checkDebugDuplicateClasses’. Flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

> A failure occurred while executing com.android.build.gradle.internal.tasks.CheckDuplicatesRunnable
> Duplicate class kotlin.collections.jdk8.CollectionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk7.JDK7PlatformImplementations$ReflectSdkVersion found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.internal.jdk8.JDK8PlatformImplementations found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.ExperimentalPathApi found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathRelativizer found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathReadWriteKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.io.path.PathsKt__PathUtilsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jdk7.AutoCloseableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk7-1.7.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:1.7.10)
> Duplicate class kotlin.jvm.jdk8.JvmRepeatableKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.random.jdk8.PlatformThreadLocalRandom found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$1 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$2 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$3 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.streams.jdk8.StreamsKt$asSequence$$inlined$Sequence$4 found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.text.jdk8.RegexExtensionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)
> Duplicate class kotlin.time.jdk8.DurationConversionsJDK8Kt found in modules jetified-kotlin-stdlib-1.8.10 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib:1.8.10) and jetified-kotlin-stdlib-jdk8-1.6.0 (org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk8:1.6.0)

```
 Go to the documentation to learn how to <a href="d.android.com/r/tools/classpath-sync-errors">Fix dependency resolution errors</a>.
```

- Try:

> Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace.
> Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
> Run with --scan to get full insights.

- Get more help at https://help.gradle.org

I was expecting that the app should run. `

app/Build.gradle

```
def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
// START: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'
// END: FlutterFire Configuration
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    namespace "com.example.vandal_course"
    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.vandal_course"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-gradle-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 19
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true

    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
    implementation "androidx.multidex:multidex:2.0.1"
}
```

Comment: Try with `flutter clean` and `flutter pub get` after. Clean and rebuild project in Android Studio could help.